# Substitute for dry milk powder

Tags: substitutions

My recipe,for dog biscuits,calls for pumpkin, rice flour, and 2 tablespoons dry milk powder. I have no milk powder, what can I use instead?

Comment: You might want to ask this at the Pets board.

Comment: A recipe would be useful, answers will be dependent on the proportion of the milk powder to other ingredients.

Comment: 2 eggs,1/2 cup canned pumpkin,2 tablespoons dry milk, 1/4 teaspoon sea salt, 2+1/2 cups brown rice flour, 1 teaspoon parsley.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace it with any other powdered non-dairy milk trivially, but I imagine you don't have those either. There's also not enough liquid in the recipe to be able to reduce it and use actual milk.

That being said, [the purpose of milk in baked goods is flavor, a tender crumb and a well-colored crust](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/dry-milk-in-bread-purpose-and-substitutions). You could add in a tablespoon of peanut butter or another fat (a local bakery makes dog biscuits with rendered bacon fat) to add tenderness to the biscuits, and your dog will probably appreciate the flavor while you can avoid the issues of canine lactose intolerance.